# loop index within index using angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a array that looks like this;

```
[
 0.{name: name, prod: [0{...}, 1{...}]},
 1.{name: name, prod: [0{...}, 1{...}]},
 2.{name: name, prod: [0{...}, 1{...}]},
 3.{name: name, prod: [0{...}, 1{...}]},
]
```

So now I do a ngfor loop using the index:

> *ngFor="let p of prodList; index as i"

This obviously gives me the first index: [0,1,2,3], however I would like to index the second array.

I have tried:

> *ngFor="let p of prodList.prod; index as i"

But does not seem to be working.

my html:

```
<ion-col size="6" *ngFor="let p of prodList; index as i">
 <h1>{{p.name}}</h1>
 <p>{{p.prod[i].description}}</p>
 <p>{{p.prod[i].price}}</p>
```

Comment: you need "concatenate loop" `<div *ngFor="let p of productList">{{p.name}}<div *ngFor="let prod of p.prod">{{prod.description}}</div</div>`. If you don't want create a new tag use [<ng-container>](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#hosting-a-directive-without-a-dom-element)

Comment: That seems to do the trick! thanks for some reason I forgot you can do that!